# Google Private account

Tags: private, account, google-account

I am unable to find the recovery option on my devices to recover my private google account, so am stuck i cant recover my account cause there is no option for lost password or recovery, need help

Comment: this question belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ not here

Comment: Also (if it hasn't already been posted, which is doubtful given Google's popularity) a better title would be helpful -- something like "How to recover access to google account".